# Remix can't flatten contract

Tags: contract-development, remix

I've used remix to deploy my contract to the mainnet and want to flatten the contract with the remix flatten plugin/module so I verify it on Etherscan. But when I click on the "Flatten contract.sol" button nothing happens.

My contract uses openzeppelin imports like so:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.1-solc-0.7/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.1-solc-0.7/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.1-solc-0.7/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

I also tried to flatten an example contract without an import and still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've just tested the flattener plugin in remix and it works as expected. I'd sugges try reloading the remix page, check the browser console for an error message.